# Java Selector select(long) vs selectNow - difference

Tags: java, select, selector

I have a system using java NIO selector. At some place I do the following in the code

```
selector.select(waitTimeOut);
```

And it works in a certain way

I replace the line above with the following

```
long loopTime = 1000;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int selects;
while (((selects = selector.selectNow()) == 0) && ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) < (waitTimeOut - loopTime))) {
  Thread.sleep(loopTime);
}
```

Now the system works differently

waitTimeOut is something like 10000

It is complicated to explain what I mean by differently. But I would expect the two alternatives to be (almost) semantically identical (except for a little bit of difference in timing with respect to when the code is finished), but I can see that they are not. Can anyone explain the difference between the two, so that I can start guessing why my system behaves differently depending on whether I use one or the other?

Comment: One second can be a _lot_ to wait sometimes

Answer (score 0):

They aren't semantically identical. The difference is that you are always sleeping for at least one second but you aren't always selecting for one second, if an event occurs within the timeout.

It's difficult to see why you would replace one line of code with six that don't work as well.

Comment: I dont see how I always sleep for one second. If the first selector.selectNow() returns != 0, then I do not sleep at all. But can I miss something by doing it this way?

Comment: If you enter the sleep, you will sleep for at least one second. Meanwhile an event can occur, but you remain asleep. select() will return immediately in the same case. This also means that more events can accumulate during your sleep, so when you wake up you have different-sized ready sets to deal with, which makes everything different from then on.

Comment: The reason I want to try this new approach is that I experience that my thread does not always continue running after waitTimeOut when doing selector.select(waitTimeOut). I have logs in the line just before and just afterwards, and there can (when my system is very loaded - but not wrt network traffic) go 100+ secs between those two logs, even though waitTimeOut is 10 secs. And that is even thought I have upped the priority of the OS-LWP (thread) behind to "RT" (chrt -f -p 99 <LWP-id>). The Selector doc says something about "no realtime guarantee", so I wanted to try this new approach

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree frankly. You're not going to improve on the kernel implementation of select(), and it's been beaten to death for decades so it's vanishingly unlikely to have any bugs.

Comment: But I iterate the ready-set, so even though a little more might have accumulated, I guess I will not miss anything. But that is where I am a little in doubt. Can I miss anything, if I handle ready-set correctly?

Comment: I do not believe the kernel has bugs, but I just cannot explain why I can see the 100+ secs in difference, when the OS thread is RT. I am not sure how Selector.select(long) maps to OS operations. It might not be that it is the OS that handles the wake-up after the timeout, but I do not no. I just cannot explain the 100+ secs, and I am 100% sure that it is happening.

Comment: What 100+ seconds? You haven't actually told us what you're observing.

Comment: When I do selector.select(10000)

Comment: When I do
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selector.select(10000);
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
When the system is very loaded (like close to 0% idle, 15% usr/sys and 85% wa), but all the IO is disk (there is no other network IO), I occasionally see "after - before" way above 10000 - it can be 50000 or even 100000. This is even though I have found the OS LWP corresponding to the java-thread doing the select and upped it to realtime OS priority (chrt -f -p 99 <LWP-id>). I want the process to continue after the 10 secs!